# for $0<a<b$, prove there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(b)-f(a) = 2cf'(c)\ln(b/a)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that for $0<a<b$ and function $f(x)$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(b)-f(a) = 2cf'(c)\ln(b/a)$. I was trying to work backwards through this but am stuck:

$$
\begin{align}
f(b)-f(a)&=2cf'(c)\ln(b/a)\\
&=2cf'(c)\,(\ln(b)-\ln(a))\\
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{\ln(b)-\ln(a)}&=2cf'(c)\\
\text{Let } g(x)&=\ln(x), g'(x)=1/x\\
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}&=\frac{2f'(c)}{g'(c)}
\end{align}$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here. Is there a theorem I should investigate from here?

Comment: The claim is false: Let $f(x)=x$, $a=1$, $b=e$. Then the claim is: "There exists $c$ with $1<c<e$ and $e-1=2c$." But that would imply $e>3$

Comment: If you forget about the factor $2$, this is the claim of [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem).